# how to install Virtualbox Guest Additions for open edX?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install open edX devstack ginkgo release on my ubuntu 16.04 but there are many errors. I followed this:
http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/index.html
but the folder edx-platform is empty.

I think it is because I can't install Virtualbox Guest Additions.

In fact `systemctl status vboxadd-service.service`gives me

`vboxadd-service.service
Loaded: not-found (Resaon: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)`

And it is the same for `service vboxguest status`.

In the log file (*/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log*) I have :

```
vboxadd.sh: failed: modprobe vboxguest failed.
```

I tried to uninstall and re install Virtualbox and Virtual Guest Additions but it doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how to switch on Virtualbox Guest Additions ? thanks